# Laravel queue with Supervisor running twice - first time without logging

Tags: laravel, redis, supervisord, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs

So, I configured my QUEUE_DRIVE with `redis`.

The `queue.php`:

```
    'redis' => [
        'driver'     => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue'      => 'default',
        'expire'     => 90,
        'retry_after' => 550
    ],
```

*Supervisor* is configured like this:

`command=php /home/xxxxx/domains/xxxxx/public_html/artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=5 --timeout=500`

The job is being dispatched like this:

```
    $job = (new CreateOrder($orderHeaderToPush, $order->order_id))
                ->delay(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1));
    dispatch($job);
```

I need the `--tries` argument to be bigger because there are multiple users doing this operation at the same time.

*PROBLEM*

Inside the job I have a `Log::Debug`. After 1 minute the job is dispatched - order comes in - No debug logging present. After a long time (the 500s) the job is dispatched again, this time logging with `Log::Debug`.

What exactly is happening? the job is not failed. How can it run without accessing the `Log::Debug` but doing other methods?

Comment: You don't need that much *retry_after*, 30 or 60 should be better and you should see your debug log before the job timeouts. You should setup a fail jobs table for your queue and check why it might be failing https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs

Comment: That is the problem. They are not `failed`. I've added 30 or 60... same problem

Comment: Same problem here, i'm running supervisor with database queue. I've still not found a solution!